# java akka default serializer warning

Tags: java, jvm, akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I do not want to disable warning messages, as I want to know how to fulfill the suggestion to define serializer in order to improve performance?

```
[INFO] [06/24/2016 19:28:34.659] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [06/24/2016 19:28:34.827] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://requesterActorSystem@127.0.0.1:41999]
[INFO] [06/24/2016 19:28:34.829] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://requesterActorSystem@127.0.0.1:41999]
[WARN] [06/24/2016 19:28:35.303] [requesterActorSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-13] [akka.serialization.Serialization(akka://requesterActorSystem)] Using the default Java serializer for class [com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig] which is not recommended because of performance implications. Use another serializer or disable this warning using the setting 'akka.actor.warn-about-java-serializer-usage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page, it is explained: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/serialization.html

In your case the default Java serializer is used, but as it is said, it is slow, so for performance reasons, it's better to use something like [`Protobuf`](https://github.com/google/protobuf) or use you own serializer.

Comment: Another option could be: https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization